# i want build docker file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

when run this command

```
sudo docker build -t jhipster /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp/src/main/docker/dockerfile1

sudo docker build -t jhipster /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp/src/main/docker/dockerfile2
```

see this error:

```
unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp/src/main/docker/dokcerfile1

unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp/src/main/docker/dokcerfile2
```

i don't know this message what is do you meaning

and i have many docker file i must build and run but i cant run any file

Comment: just run this: `sudo docker build -t jhipster /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp/src/main/docker/`, you need to provide the path of the directory to build a docker image and not the dockerfile path

Comment: I see some more problems, why do you have multiple dockerfiles in the same directory. also the dockerfile name has to be `Dockerfile`, it can't have suffixes like `dockerfile1`, etc.

Comment: i have  app.yml ,jhipster-rigster.yml, kafka.yml and ..etc

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docker build docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f), if you're specifying a Dockerfile that's either not exactly named `Dockerfile` or is not in your current directory, you should use the `-f` flag.

The error is telling you you provided an invalid build context. The build context should be a directory that contains anything you need to `COPY` or `ADD` into the image. Any `COPY` commands you have would be relative to the build context path.

Here's how you could use the `-f` flag and build context:

```
sudo docker build -t TAGNAME -f /path/to/dockerfile /path/to/build/context
```

For you, it really depends on the contents of your Dockerfile but your full command might be something like this:

```
sudo docker build -t jhipster -f /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp/src/main/docker/dockerfile1 /home/abed/project/microServies/StudentApp
```

Comment: where i can find build/context

Comment: @AbdalrhmanAlkraien It depends on the contents of your Dockerfile. It's likely the root directory of your source code. You can post your Dockerfile as well and that might help.